# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.print.PrintServiceLookup in ANDROID

Tags: android, android-layout, android-library, java

I am working on a android project which should display all the printer and have to take print in Android. I have used `JAVAX` library system library for my android project.

Here is how I added libraries to my application:

```
Open project properties by right clicking project and selecting properties
Select JAVA build path on the left pane
Select Libraries tab from right side
Click add Library button
Select JRE system library and add required package.
```

Mainactivity java code:

```
package com.example.codeandroidprinter;

import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button print = (Button) findViewById(R.id.print);

        print.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ddd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                try
                {
                    String printernames="";
                    PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
                    for (int i = 0; i < printServices.length; i++) { 
                        PrintService printer = printServices[i];
                        printernames =   printernames + printer.getName() + ",";    
                    }
                    System.out.print(printernames);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

Xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.codeandroidprinter.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/print"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

when i click the button, i got result as

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.print.PrintServiceLookup
```

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: javax.print package is not a part of android api

Answer (score 2):

> I have used JAVAX library system library for my android project.

That will not work. Android generally will not load `java`/`javax` classes from elsewhere, and as Selvin notes, `javax.print` is not part of Android itself.

> I am working on a android project which should display all the printer and have to take print in Android.

You are welcome to use [the printing APIs added to Android 4.4](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html). Prior to that, there was no printing support in Android, though various third-party tools (e.g., Google Cloud Print) offered various ways for people to connect to specific printers.

Comment: then how can we achieve this for android version below 4.4 ?

Comment: @shankark: You connect your printers to something, like Google Cloud Print, that offers some sort of on-device API. Such an API is likely to be rather limited -- I seem to recall that with Google Cloud Print, all you could do was send it a document to be printed, and it took over from there.

Comment: @shankark: "we cant able to print from programmer?" -- any of the Java printing APIs, including the one you tried to use and failed, requires you to create some sort of document to be printed. Whether that document already exists as a file or is something that you create programmatically is up to the programmer. "GCP is the only OPTIONS ?" -- please stop shouting. You are welcome to research whether printer manufacturers (e.g., HP) or other third parties created GCP-like solutions. The OS itself does not support printing until Android 4.4.